# how to add NYC map bound in plot using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

How can I add NYC map bound into my plot.nycmap dataset include longitude,latitude,and price variable.

```html
longitude latitude price
-70.23  49.34   120
-20.31  30.26   56
...
```

```
min_lat <- 40.5774
max_lat <- 40.9176
min_long <- -74.15
max_long <- -73.7004

library(ggmap)
library(ggthemes)

plot <- ggplot(mapnyc, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude,color =logprice),alpha =0.03) +
            geom_point(size=0.8) +
            scale_x_continuous(limits=c(min_long, max_long)) +
            scale_y_continuous(limits=c(min_lat, max_lat)) 
plot
```

So I want to get spatial plots in NYC map bound? In my plot,I don't have bound there.
[image]

Comment: is `mapnyc` a ggmap object?

Comment: @Stedy Its a dataset... I just update sample dataset in the file..

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the ggmap package, I would suggest using `ggmap()` function:

```
mapnyc <- data.frame(latitude = c(40.7032815,40.7082398),
                     longitude = c(-74.0192166, -74.0054436),
                     logprice = c(120,56))
nyc_base <- ggmap::get_map("New York City", zoom = 14)
ggmap(nyc_base) + geom_point(data=mapnyc, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude), color="red", size=20, alpha=0.5)
```

**Note:** I could not make sense of your original data with regards to your bounding box so I just made my own data.

[image]